# What data type is used for storing "star" ⭐in mongoose?

Tags: mongoose, schema

I am making a schema for the review module for an e-commerce website. Hence, I would like to save "Rating" with start ⭐ but I don't know if I should store in String or any other mongoose data type.

Comment: It is a unicode character. String with UTF-8 will work